# Deleting folders in Windows XP

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp

I reinstalled Win XP 64 on a computer that previously had Win 7 installed. I would like to be able to delete all the contents of 'Program Files' (associated with Win 7) but I run into permission errors. I tried out FileASSASSIN, but this will not let me delete a folder.

Is there any way I can remove this folder?

Comment: What makes you sure the 'Program Files' is only associated with Windows 7? Is Xp installed on a different drive from Windows 7?

Comment: The xp installation files are all in a folder called 'Program Files (x86)'

Comment: Did you try taking ownership of the folder?

Comment: No. Some of the XP files will be  'Program Files (x86)' but others will be in 'Program files'. Basically the 64-bit native programs will be in 'Program Files' whilst 32-bit programs will be in 'Program Files (x86)'.

Answer (score 1):

Woha, back up for a minute.

Windows needs "Program Files" regardless of if you are running 32 or 64bit.
In Windows 64bit, Windows uses "Program Files" folder to store all the programs that are ran as a 64bit program. (such as IE) Windows uses "Programs Files (x86)" to install programs that will be ran as a 32bit program.

In short, you can't and wouldn't want to delete "Program Files" folder. What you should do instead is go into "Program Files" and delete programs you don't want anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Take ownership of the folder then you should be able to add the permissions to be able to delete just make sure you you dont need anything.  Thanks!

Comment: This should be a comment on the question. Thanks!

Comment: No the is probably what he needs to do.

Comment: I have full permission to edit the folder (with the exception of some 'read only' files).